# Create new empty type product

Tags: magento2, custom-product-type

I would like to create new Type product (as Configurable, Simple, ...).

Here my code :

module.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Project_CustomType" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

product_type.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="custom_type" label="CustomType Product" modelInstance="Project\CustomType\Model\Product\Type\CustomType" indexPriority="60" sortOrder="80" isQty="true">
    </type>
</config>
```

CustomType.php :

```
<?php
namespace Project\CustomType\Model\Product\Type;

class CustomType extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType
{
    const TYPE_CODE = 'custom_type';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     */
    public function deleteTypeSpecificData(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {

    }
}
```

I created new attributes that I assigned to my new product type.

But here my problem :

When I want to create a new CustomType product in my BO, I need to fill all default attributes + my custom attributes.

But I don't want to fill default attributes : I would like to fill only my custom attributes.

Where do I need to specify that I don't want to create my new CustomType product with default attributes like Enable Product, Attribute Set, Product Name, ... ?

Any idea ?